# SQL Query to Cdbcriteria

Tags: yii

I have a SQL query like this

```
SELECT * 
FROM nu.tb_class t 
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT st_id FROM student_class s WHERE s.st_id = t.id)
```

I need this to put it Cdbcriteria can any tell me how to do this ?

(somehow I need to put this data to CGridView if there is any other way I like to know it)

Comment: do u have relationship between the two models if yes then can u post that relations here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the NotInCondition in your Criteria
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria#addNotInCondition-detail

Note: that it takes an array, that means you have to select only the st_id column, and pass it to the addNotInCondition function ... the easy way to do this is some thing like:

```
$st_ids = CHtml::listData(StudentClass::model()->findAll($criteria)), 'column1', 'column2');
```

And for sure you can run it as sql query, then use the CArrayDataProvider 
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/database.dao#executing-sql-statements
http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CArrayDataProvider

Answer (score 2):

You can convert that query to an equivalent LEFT JOIN query:

```
$classes = TbClass::model()->findAll(array(
    'condition' => 's.st_id IS NULL',
    'join' => 'LEFT JOIN student_class s ON t.id=s.st_id',
));
```

Notice that you can pass the properties of a [`CDbCriteria`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CDbCriteria) to [`findAll()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CActiveRecord#findAll-detail).